# Getting started with django using Tango with Django

Tags: python, django

How good is the resource [Tango with Django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/), for getting started with django ?
Given that I have finished basic [Writing your first django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial from official django website ?

Answer (score 7):

I reviewed briefly the tutorial pages and seems to be great.
My thoughts:

- Easier then official doc.
- Introduces some common practices, where Django doc is missing.
- No additional knowledge is needed, everything included.

The tutorial is up-to-date(But currently only for Django 1.5.4). Authors are:

**Leif Azzopardi** is an Associate Professor at the University of Glasgow who teaches Web Development, Web Design, Information Architecture and Software Engineering. His research focuses on Information Retrieval.
**David Maxwell** is a PhD Candidate at the University of Glasgow, who teaches Python and Web Development. His research also focuses on Information Retrieval.

You can see also @tangowithdjango on twitter is quite popular.

Remember tutorial is not everything. You should visit regularly Python and Django Docs.